# Unable to Show onComingCall ViewController for my iOS VoIP Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip

I want my App to show IncomingCall ViewController, when App Receives Some Incoming Call.

This is my Code that I uses to show Incoming Call.. From my ContactsViewController, which is Active View when Incoming Call take places.

```
- (void)showIncomigCallVC{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToIncomingCallVC" sender:nil];
}
```

This is my Code, that is called by Library.

```
    /* Callback called by the library upon receiving incoming call */
static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id,
                         pjsip_rx_data *rdata)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(acc_id);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(rdata);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);



    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "....\n\n\n Incoming call from %.*s!!  \n\n\n",
          (int)ci.remote_info.slen,
          ci.remote_info.ptr));

    ContactsViewController *incomingCallVC = [[ContactsViewController alloc]init];
    [incomingCallVC showIncomigCallVC];

    /* Automatically answer incoming calls with 200/OK */
    pjsua_call_answer(call_id, 200, NULL, NULL);
}
```

And This is my Console Output:

```
20:39:37.482      XCPjsua.c  ......


Incoming call from <sip:eeshaMiss12@ekiga.net>!!  



2017-01-16 20:39:37.494 simpleVoIP[922:19652] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ContactsViewController: 0x7bea3d00>) has  no segue with identifier 'segueToIncomingCallVC''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03a14212 __exceptionPreprocess + 194
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x034d3e66 objc_exception_throw + 52
    2   UIKit                               0x01a69893 -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
    3   simpleVoIP                          0x00089ba6 -[ContactsViewController showIncomigCallVC] + 70
    4   simpleVoIP                          0x00086caf on_incoming_call + 255
    5   simpleVoIP                          0x000fc273 pjsua_call_on_incoming + 3811
    6   simpleVoIP                          0x00103294 mod_pjsua_on_rx_request + 84
    7   simpleVoIP                          0x0012938f pjsip_endpt_process_rx_data + 351
    8   simpleVoIP                          0x00128bf2 endpt_on_rx_msg + 546
    9   simpleVoIP                          0x0012fba1 pjsip_tpmgr_receive_packet + 849
    10  simpleVoIP                          0x001315ec udp_on_read_complete + 316
    11  simpleVoIP                          0x0014b8e0 ioqueue_dispatch_read_event + 704
    12  simpleVoIP                          0x0014d5b2 pj_ioqueue_poll + 946
    13  simpleVoIP                          0x001290c3 pjsip_endpt_handle_events2 + 163
    14  simpleVoIP                          0x00102023 worker_thread + 99
    15  simpleVoIP                          0x0014eb96 thread_main + 86
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04c8a11b _pthread_body + 184
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04c8a063 _pthread_body + 0
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04c8993e thread_start + 34
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am Beginner, any Recommendation will be appreciated.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just read the error: `ContactsViewController`, from where you are calling `showIncomigCallVC` has no segue on the storyboard set up with the identifier `segueToIncomingCallVC `. To resolve our problem, can you please show `ContactsViewController` on the storyboard? Especially the part, where you have the segues set up. I am expecting something like this: http://imgur.com/a/SMKjT

Comment: yeah..! I can show and thanks for response

Comment: @dirtydanee see this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9eGVWZOsrOmRHVsMENTNTBQTHc

Comment: ok, it seems to be fine. Please, try adding `self` to the `performSegueWithIdentifier` function call.
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToIncomingCallVC" sender:self];`

Comment: @dirtydanee : Same error occurs: 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ContactsViewController: 0x7aaabfe0>) has no segue with identifier 'segueToIncomingCallVC''

Comment: May be this occurs, Due to usage of PJSIP library ?? and the control from CallBack is send here To show some UI, before receiving the call..... :/
Because in other cases it works fine.

Comment: yes, kind of. I am writting my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing the crash, because you are programatically allocating your `ContactsViewController`, instead of using from the `storyboard`.

When you do this:

```
 ContactsViewController *incomingCallVC = [[ContactsViewController alloc]init];
 [incomingCallVC showIncomigCallVC];
```

You are creating an instance of `ContactsViewController`, what has nothing to do with the one created in our `storyboard`.
It would be possible to overcome on this, however, you are trying to make a `segue` call on a `viewController`, what has only been loaded to the memory, but is not visible at all. That will never work, it will always crash.

I would recommend to show your `viewController`, whatever is behind the segue, straight away, instead of creating a `viewController` and show it with a segue.

**EDIT**:

Using the code below, you should be able to present your desired `UIViewController` subclass from the end of your callback function.

```
// Lets get keywindow 
UIWindow* keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]; 
keyWindow.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds; 

// Lets get `IncomingCallViewController` from storyboard 
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TheNameOfYourStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 
// do not forget to set the identifier of your viewController on the storyboard as "IncomingCallViewController" 
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IncomingCallViewController"]; 
// Lets present the keyWindow from the main thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
   keyWindow.rootViewController = vc; 
   [keyWindow makeKeyAndVisible]; 
});
```

Comment: please, let me know about your progress.

Comment: You mean, I should do this coding?

ContactsViewController *incomingCallVC;
 [incomingCallVC showIncomigCallVC];

Comment: Remove allocation and initialization?

Comment: no, it is the concept, you are doing is wrong. What is the name of the viewController you would like to show?

Comment: Nothing displayed, while incoming the Call.

Comment: The name of the ViewController I'd like to show: IncomingCallViewController

Comment: have you already have a viewController in memory, when you receive the callback? or where is this callback declared? In the `AppDelegate` ?

Comment: Not understanding your Question, but if you asking, if some view controller is already shown, while receiving the callBack, then the Answer is Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133294/discussion-between-dirtydanee-and-eesha).